# Getting docker containers output from another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipc

I have an application that runs dockerized commands via `docker run --rm ...`. Is it possible to dockerize this application?

E.g. I want the app `RUNNER` to run app `RUNNABLE` and read the stdout result.
(I need multiple instances of `RUNNABLE` in async calling fashion but that's `RUNNER` application business)

I know it is possible to just export root access to docker socket to the `RUNNER` application but this doesn't feel right. Especially with no-root-running rule for *nix applications.

Is there any other method to communicate containers rather than exporting socket to the container? Am I doing the system design wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's possible to let the container communicate over host based files. Take a look at the following example.

```
# create a test dir
mkdir -p docker_test/bin
cd docker_test
# an endless running script that writes output in a file
vim bin/printDate.sh
chmod 700 bin/*.sh
# start docker container from debian image
# the container got a local host mount of /tmp to container /opt/output
# printDate.sh writes its output to container /opt/output/printDate.txt
docker run --name cont-1 \
  -v /tmp:/opt/output -it -v `pwd`/bin:/opt/test \
  debian /opt/test/printDate.sh

# start a second container in another terminal and mount /tmp again
docker run --name cont-2 -v /tmp:/opt/output -it \
  debian tail -f /opt/output/printDate.txt
# the second container prints the output of program in cont-1
```

The endless script for container 1 output

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
     sleep 1
     date >> /opt/output/printDate.txt
done
```